# Tensorflow GPU: Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying machine learning, for which i would like to use my gpu.

**The full error**

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:10.458853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-09-28 20:46:15.734698: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.735244: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.735713: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.736190: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.736661: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.737111: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.737551: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.737998: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2022-09-28 20:46:15.738241: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2022-09-28 20:46:15.739282: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-09-28 20:46:15.776016: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

The following test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
#import os
#os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin")

print(tf.add(1, 2))
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print(tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

results in :

```
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32)
True
True
[]
2022-09-28 20:46:15.776016: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8872492517262768871
xla_global_id: -1
]
```

**My system**

- GTX GeForce 1650 Ti , which should be good for CUDA

Following the tensorflow installation: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

- i used CUDA 11.2, which is in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
- cuDNNN 8.0.1, from which i copied the files in the respective bin, include, lib folders(so cudart64_110.dll is present in the bin folder)
- i got visual studio from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
- i am working in a pycharm venv, with packagas installed: keras, tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu, tf-nightly, cudatools

Using a general cmd terminal(not in an ide), `nvcc --version` returns good results, so does`nvidia-smi`

Tried some stuff from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43193, but nothing i tried worked.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There might be an issue with the environment variables. Check that you have something like `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\cuda\bin` in your `Path` Environment variable and that the variables `CUDA_PATH` and `CUDA_PATH_V11_2` are set to something like `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2`. Also check that there is no other version of cuda installed and referenced somewhere in the environment variables.

Comment: Hi @BrechtDeCock, please make sure that you are downloading a compatible Version of CUDA  with tensorflow mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Also add CuDA path to environmental variable by following these [steps](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/environment_variables.htm). Thank You.